# Rspec can not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run

```
rspec .
```

I get error log like this:

```
/Users/max/dev/Circle/lib/active_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `require'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb:5:in `each'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/spec/spec_helper.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/spec/spec_helper.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/spec/controllers/admin/applies_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/max/dev/Circle/spec/controllers/admin/applies_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I've installed the gem rspec and rspec-rails, but error still happened. Thanks for saving my day.

*EDIT 1:*

Gemfile is like this:

```
source 'http://ruby.taobao.org'

gem "rails", "~> 3.2.9"

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'

gem 'exception_notification'

gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails'

gem 'cancan'

gem 'slim-rails'

gem "jqcloud-rails"

gem 'omniauth'

gem 'omniauth-oauth2'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'

gem 'acts_as_commentable', '3.0.1'

gem "acts_as_follower"

gem "select2-rails"

gem 'roadie'

gem 'rails_config'

gem 'daemons'

gem 'rmagick'

gem 'awesome_print'

gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'paperclip', '= 3.1.2'

gem 'cocaine', '= 0.3.2'

gem "will_paginate"

gem "bootstrap-will_paginate"

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', "2.2.0"

gem 'therubyracer', "0.11.1",:platforms => :ruby

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'client_side_validations'

gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

gem "responders"

gem 'inherited_resources'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem 'redis'

gem 'redis-objects'

gem 'watir-webdriver'

gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'ruby-pinyin'

gem 'state_machine'

gem 'sitemap_generator'

gem 'ga_measurement', :git => 'https://github.com/nickcen/ga_measurement'

group :assets do

  gem 'sass-rails'

  gem 'coffee-rails'

  gem 'libv8'

  gem 'therubyracer','0.11.1'

  gem 'uglifier'

end

gem 'enumerize'

group :development do

  gem "letter_opener"

  gem "better_errors"#, :git => 'git://github.com/charliesome/better_errors.git'

  gem "binding_of_caller"

  gem 'pry-rails'

  gem "thin"

end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do

  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3'

end

group :test, :development do

  gem 'rspec-rails'

end
```

Gemfile.lock is this this:

```
GIT


  remote: https://github.com/nickcen/ga_measurement


  revision: ecaaabdca410136d75975c3cb6a421e62a7c2d53


  specs:


    ga_measurement (0.0.1)


      rest-client





GEM


  remote: http://ruby.taobao.org/


  specs:


    actionmailer (3.2.13)


      actionpack (= 3.2.13)


      mail (~> 2.5.3)


    actionpack (3.2.13)


      activemodel (= 3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


      builder (~> 3.0.0)


      erubis (~> 2.7.0)


      journey (~> 1.0.4)


      rack (~> 1.4.5)


      rack-cache (~> 1.2)


      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)


      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)


    activemodel (3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


      builder (~> 3.0.0)


    activerecord (3.2.13)


      activemodel (= 3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


      arel (~> 3.0.2)


      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)


    activeresource (3.2.13)


      activemodel (= 3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


    activesupport (3.2.13)


      i18n (= 0.6.1)


      multi_json (~> 1.0)


    acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)


      rails (>= 3, < 5)


    acts_as_commentable (3.0.1)


    acts_as_follower (0.1.1)


    addressable (2.3.4)


    ansi (1.4.3)


    arel (3.0.2)


    awesome_print (1.1.0)


    better_errors (0.9.0)


      coderay (>= 1.0.0)


      erubis (>= 2.6.6)


    binding_of_caller (0.7.1)


      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)


    bootstrap-editable-rails (0.0.5)


      railties (>= 3.1)


    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)


      will_paginate


    builder (3.0.4)


    cancan (1.6.10)


    childprocess (0.3.9)


      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)


    client_side_validations (3.2.5)


    client_side_validations-simple_form (2.1.0)


      client_side_validations (~> 3.2.5)


      simple_form (~> 2.1.0)


    cocaine (0.3.2)


    coderay (1.0.9)


    coffee-rails (3.2.2)


      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)


      railties (~> 3.2.0)


    coffee-script (2.2.0)


      coffee-script-source


      execjs


    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)


    css_parser (1.3.4)


      addressable


    daemons (1.1.9)


    debug_inspector (0.0.2)


    delayed_job (3.0.5)


      activesupport (~> 3.0)


    delayed_job_active_record (0.4.4)


      activerecord (>= 2.1.0, < 4)


      delayed_job (~> 3.0)


    diff-lcs (1.2.4)


    enumerize (0.6.1)


      activesupport (>= 3.2)


    erubis (2.7.0)


    eventmachine (1.0.3)


    exception_notification (3.0.1)


      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)


    execjs (1.4.0)


      multi_json (~> 1.0)


    faraday (0.8.7)


      multipart-post (~> 1.1)


    ffi (1.8.1)


    font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2)


      railties (>= 3.1.1)


      sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)


    has_scope (0.5.1)


    hashie (2.0.5)


    hike (1.2.3)


    httpauth (0.2.0)


    i18n (0.6.1)


    inherited_resources (1.4.0)


      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)


      responders (~> 0.9)


    journey (1.0.4)


    jqcloud-rails (1.0.0)


      jquery-rails


    jquery-rails (3.0.0)


      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)


      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)


    json (1.8.0)


    jwt (0.1.8)


      multi_json (>= 1.5)


    launchy (2.3.0)


      addressable (~> 2.3)


    letter_opener (1.1.1)


      launchy (~> 2.2)


    libv8 (3.11.8.17)


    mail (2.5.4)


      mime-types (~> 1.16)


      treetop (~> 1.4.8)


    method_source (0.8.1)


    mime-types (1.23)


    mini_magick (3.6.0)


      subexec (~> 0.2.1)


    multi_json (1.7.6)


    multipart-post (1.2.0)


    mysql2 (0.3.11)


    newrelic_rpm (3.6.3.106)


    nokogiri (1.5.9)


    oauth2 (0.8.1)


      faraday (~> 0.8)


      httpauth (~> 0.1)


      jwt (~> 0.1.4)


      multi_json (~> 1.0)


      rack (~> 1.2)


    omniauth (1.1.4)


      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)


      rack


    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)


      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)


      omniauth (~> 1.0)


    paperclip (3.1.2)


      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)


      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)


      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)


      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)


      mime-types


    polyglot (0.3.3)


    pry (0.9.12.2)


      coderay (~> 1.0.5)


      method_source (~> 0.8)


      slop (~> 3.4)


    pry-rails (0.3.0)


      pry (>= 0.9.10)


    rack (1.4.5)


    rack-cache (1.2)


      rack (>= 0.4)


    rack-ssl (1.3.3)


      rack


    rack-test (0.6.2)


      rack (>= 1.0)


    rails (3.2.13)


      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)


      actionpack (= 3.2.13)


      activerecord (= 3.2.13)


      activeresource (= 3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


      bundler (~> 1.0)


      railties (= 3.2.13)


    rails_config (0.3.3)


      activesupport (>= 3.0)


    railties (3.2.13)


      actionpack (= 3.2.13)


      activesupport (= 3.2.13)


      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)


      rake (>= 0.8.7)


      rdoc (~> 3.4)


      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)


    rake (10.0.4)


    rdoc (3.12.2)


      json (~> 1.4)


    redis (3.0.4)


    redis-objects (0.7.0)


      redis (>= 3.0.2)


    ref (1.0.5)


    responders (0.9.3)


      railties (~> 3.1)


    rest-client (1.6.7)


      mime-types (>= 1.16)


    rmagick (2.13.2)


    roadie (2.3.4)


      actionmailer (> 3.0.0, < 3.3.0)


      css_parser


      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)


      sprockets


    rspec-core (2.13.1)


    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)


      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)


    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)


    rspec-rails (2.13.2)


      actionpack (>= 3.0)


      activesupport (>= 3.0)


      railties (>= 3.0)


      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)


      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)


      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)


    ruby-pinyin (0.2.1)


    rubyzip (0.9.9)


    sass (3.2.9)


    sass-rails (3.2.6)


      railties (~> 3.2.0)


      sass (>= 3.1.10)


      tilt (~> 1.3)


    select2-rails (3.4.1)


      sass-rails


      thor (~> 0.14)


    selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)


      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)


      multi_json (~> 1.0)


      rubyzip


      websocket (~> 1.0.4)


    simple_form (2.1.0)


      actionpack (~> 3.0)


      activemodel (~> 3.0)


    sitemap_generator (4.1.0)


      builder


    slim (2.0.0)


      temple (~> 0.6.5)


      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)


    slim-rails (2.0.1)


      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.1)


      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)


      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.1)


      slim (~> 2.0)


    slop (3.4.5)


    sprockets (2.2.2)


      hike (~> 1.2)


      multi_json (~> 1.0)


      rack (~> 1.0)


      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)


    state_machine (1.2.0)


    subexec (0.2.3)


    temple (0.6.5)


    therubyracer (0.11.1)


      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.7)


      ref


    thin (1.5.1)


      daemons (>= 1.0.9)


      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)


      rack (>= 1.0.0)


    thor (0.18.1)


    tilt (1.4.1)


    treetop (1.4.14)


      polyglot


      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)


    turn (0.8.3)


      ansi


    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.0)


      actionpack (>= 3.1)


      execjs


      railties (>= 3.1)


    tzinfo (0.3.37)


    uglifier (2.1.1)


      execjs (>= 0.3.0)


      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)


    watir-webdriver (0.6.4)


      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.18.0)


    websocket (1.0.7)


    will_paginate (3.0.4)





PLATFORMS


  ruby





DEPENDENCIES


  acts-as-taggable-on


  acts_as_commentable (= 3.0.1)


  acts_as_follower


  awesome_print


  better_errors


  binding_of_caller


  bootstrap-editable-rails


  bootstrap-will_paginate


  cancan


  client_side_validations


  client_side_validations-simple_form


  cocaine (= 0.3.2)


  coffee-rails


  daemons


  delayed_job_active_record


  enumerize


  exception_notification


  font-awesome-sass-rails


  ga_measurement!


  inherited_resources


  jqcloud-rails


  jquery-rails


  letter_opener


  libv8


  mini_magick


  mysql2


  newrelic_rpm


  nokogiri


  omniauth


  omniauth-oauth2


  paperclip (= 3.1.2)


  pry-rails


  rails (~> 3.2.9)


  rails_config


  redis


  redis-objects


  responders


  rmagick


  roadie


  rspec-rails


  ruby-pinyin


  sass-rails


  select2-rails


  simple_form


  sitemap_generator


  slim-rails


  state_machine


  therubyracer (= 0.11.1)


  thin


  turn (~> 0.8.3)


  twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 2.2.0)


  uglifier


  watir-webdriver


  will_paginate


GIT

  remote: https://github.com/nickcen/ga_measurement

  revision: ecaaabdca410136d75975c3cb6a421e62a7c2d53

  specs:

    ga_measurement (0.0.1)

      rest-client



GEM

  remote: http://ruby.taobao.org/

  specs:

    actionmailer (3.2.13)

      actionpack (= 3.2.13)

      mail (~> 2.5.3)

    actionpack (3.2.13)

      activemodel (= 3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

      builder (~> 3.0.0)

      erubis (~> 2.7.0)

      journey (~> 1.0.4)

      rack (~> 1.4.5)

      rack-cache (~> 1.2)

      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)

      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)

    activemodel (3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

      builder (~> 3.0.0)

    activerecord (3.2.13)

      activemodel (= 3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

      arel (~> 3.0.2)

      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)

    activeresource (3.2.13)

      activemodel (= 3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

    activesupport (3.2.13)

      i18n (= 0.6.1)

      multi_json (~> 1.0)

    acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)

      rails (>= 3, < 5)

    acts_as_commentable (3.0.1)

    acts_as_follower (0.1.1)

    addressable (2.3.4)

    ansi (1.4.3)

    arel (3.0.2)

    awesome_print (1.1.0)

    better_errors (0.9.0)

      coderay (>= 1.0.0)

      erubis (>= 2.6.6)

    binding_of_caller (0.7.1)

      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)

    bootstrap-editable-rails (0.0.5)

      railties (>= 3.1)

    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)

      will_paginate

    builder (3.0.4)

    cancan (1.6.10)

    childprocess (0.3.9)

      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)

    client_side_validations (3.2.5)

    client_side_validations-simple_form (2.1.0)

      client_side_validations (~> 3.2.5)

      simple_form (~> 2.1.0)

    cocaine (0.3.2)

    coderay (1.0.9)

    coffee-rails (3.2.2)

      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)

      railties (~> 3.2.0)

    coffee-script (2.2.0)

      coffee-script-source

      execjs

    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)

    css_parser (1.3.4)

      addressable

    daemons (1.1.9)

    debug_inspector (0.0.2)

    delayed_job (3.0.5)

      activesupport (~> 3.0)

    delayed_job_active_record (0.4.4)

      activerecord (>= 2.1.0, < 4)

      delayed_job (~> 3.0)

    diff-lcs (1.2.4)

    enumerize (0.6.1)

      activesupport (>= 3.2)

    erubis (2.7.0)

    eventmachine (1.0.3)

    exception_notification (3.0.1)

      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)

    execjs (1.4.0)

      multi_json (~> 1.0)

    faraday (0.8.7)

      multipart-post (~> 1.1)

    ffi (1.8.1)

    font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2)

      railties (>= 3.1.1)

      sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)

    has_scope (0.5.1)

    hashie (2.0.5)

    hike (1.2.3)

    httpauth (0.2.0)

    i18n (0.6.1)

    inherited_resources (1.4.0)

      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)

      responders (~> 0.9)

    journey (1.0.4)

    jqcloud-rails (1.0.0)

      jquery-rails

    jquery-rails (3.0.0)

      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)

    json (1.8.0)

    jwt (0.1.8)

      multi_json (>= 1.5)

    launchy (2.3.0)

      addressable (~> 2.3)

    letter_opener (1.1.1)

      launchy (~> 2.2)

    libv8 (3.11.8.17)

    mail (2.5.4)

      mime-types (~> 1.16)

      treetop (~> 1.4.8)

    method_source (0.8.1)

    mime-types (1.23)

    mini_magick (3.6.0)

      subexec (~> 0.2.1)

    multi_json (1.7.6)

    multipart-post (1.2.0)

    mysql2 (0.3.11)

    newrelic_rpm (3.6.3.106)

    nokogiri (1.5.9)

    oauth2 (0.8.1)

      faraday (~> 0.8)

      httpauth (~> 0.1)

      jwt (~> 0.1.4)

      multi_json (~> 1.0)

      rack (~> 1.2)

    omniauth (1.1.4)

      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)

      rack

    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)

      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)

      omniauth (~> 1.0)

    paperclip (3.1.2)

      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)

      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)

      mime-types

    polyglot (0.3.3)

    pry (0.9.12.2)

      coderay (~> 1.0.5)

      method_source (~> 0.8)

      slop (~> 3.4)

    pry-rails (0.3.0)

      pry (>= 0.9.10)

    rack (1.4.5)

    rack-cache (1.2)

      rack (>= 0.4)

    rack-ssl (1.3.3)

      rack

    rack-test (0.6.2)

      rack (>= 1.0)

    rails (3.2.13)

      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)

      actionpack (= 3.2.13)

      activerecord (= 3.2.13)

      activeresource (= 3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

      bundler (~> 1.0)

      railties (= 3.2.13)

    rails_config (0.3.3)

      activesupport (>= 3.0)

    railties (3.2.13)

      actionpack (= 3.2.13)

      activesupport (= 3.2.13)

      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)

      rake (>= 0.8.7)

      rdoc (~> 3.4)

      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)

    rake (10.0.4)

    rdoc (3.12.2)

      json (~> 1.4)

    redis (3.0.4)

    redis-objects (0.7.0)

      redis (>= 3.0.2)

    ref (1.0.5)

    responders (0.9.3)

      railties (~> 3.1)

    rest-client (1.6.7)

      mime-types (>= 1.16)

    rmagick (2.13.2)

    roadie (2.3.4)

      actionmailer (> 3.0.0, < 3.3.0)

      css_parser

      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)

      sprockets

    rspec-core (2.13.1)

    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)

      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)

    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)

    rspec-rails (2.13.2)

      actionpack (>= 3.0)

      activesupport (>= 3.0)

      railties (>= 3.0)

      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)

      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)

      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)

    ruby-pinyin (0.2.1)

    rubyzip (0.9.9)

    sass (3.2.9)

    sass-rails (3.2.6)

      railties (~> 3.2.0)

      sass (>= 3.1.10)

      tilt (~> 1.3)

    select2-rails (3.4.1)

      sass-rails

      thor (~> 0.14)

    selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)

      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)

      multi_json (~> 1.0)

      rubyzip

      websocket (~> 1.0.4)

    simple_form (2.1.0)

      actionpack (~> 3.0)

      activemodel (~> 3.0)

    sitemap_generator (4.1.0)

      builder

    slim (2.0.0)

      temple (~> 0.6.5)

      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)

    slim-rails (2.0.1)

      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.1)

      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)

      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.1)

      slim (~> 2.0)

    slop (3.4.5)

    sprockets (2.2.2)

      hike (~> 1.2)

      multi_json (~> 1.0)

      rack (~> 1.0)

      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)

    state_machine (1.2.0)

    subexec (0.2.3)

    temple (0.6.5)

    therubyracer (0.11.1)

      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.7)

      ref

    thin (1.5.1)

      daemons (>= 1.0.9)

      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)

      rack (>= 1.0.0)

    thor (0.18.1)

    tilt (1.4.1)

    treetop (1.4.14)

      polyglot

      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)

    turn (0.8.3)

      ansi

    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.0)

      actionpack (>= 3.1)

      execjs

      railties (>= 3.1)

    tzinfo (0.3.37)

    uglifier (2.1.1)

      execjs (>= 0.3.0)

      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

    watir-webdriver (0.6.4)

      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.18.0)

    websocket (1.0.7)

    will_paginate (3.0.4)



PLATFORMS

  ruby



DEPENDENCIES

  acts-as-taggable-on

  acts_as_commentable (= 3.0.1)

  acts_as_follower

  awesome_print

  better_errors

  binding_of_caller

  bootstrap-editable-rails

  bootstrap-will_paginate

  cancan

  client_side_validations

  client_side_validations-simple_form

  cocaine (= 0.3.2)

  coffee-rails

  daemons

  delayed_job_active_record

  enumerize

  exception_notification

  font-awesome-sass-rails

  ga_measurement!

  inherited_resources

  jqcloud-rails

  jquery-rails

  letter_opener

  libv8

  mini_magick

  mysql2

  newrelic_rpm

  nokogiri

  omniauth

  omniauth-oauth2

  paperclip (= 3.1.2)

  pry-rails

  rails (~> 3.2.9)

  rails_config

  redis

  redis-objects

  responders

  rmagick

  roadie

  rspec-rails

  ruby-pinyin

  sass-rails

  select2-rails

  simple_form

  sitemap_generator

  slim-rails

  state_machine

  therubyracer (= 0.11.1)

  thin

  turn (~> 0.8.3)

  twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 2.2.0)

  uglifier

  watir-webdriver

  will_paginate
```

Comment: Yes, I've included "gem 'rspec-rails'" in Gemfile

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: OK, I add a new edit, a bit long, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem fixed by reinstalling rvm. And rpsec works.

1. install rvm:

   `bash -s 1.18.6 < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)`
2. install ruby:

   `rvm install 1.9.3`
3. if come up with bug when retrieving rubygems:

   `rvm rubygems current --verify-downloads 1`
4. cd /path/to/project

   `sudo gem install bundler`

   `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Call rspec from [Bundler](http://bundler.io):

```
bundle exec rspec .
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to run some commands to prepare for testing

just run `rake db:test:prepare`

than try your test commands `rspec .`

Comment: Still the same error. I guess there are errors of my system configuration, so ActiveRecord cannot be loaded.